# Java: How to count a character in a String using Loop?

Tags: java, string, loops

I am wondering how to count the number of times that a letter entered by a user appears in a string that is also entered by a user. I have to use Loops and if/else statements. I think I'm on the right track, but I get caught up when compiling (using BlueJ), with the error message "cannot find symbol - variable position". Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

```
String input;
String sentence;
String letter;
int times=0;
int position;

Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Please enter a string: ");
input = kb.nextLine();

sentence = input.toLowerCase();

System.out.print("Thank you.\nPlease enter the character you wish to be counted: ");
letter = kb.next();

for (position=0; position<=sentence.length(); position++) {
    if (sentence.charAt(position) == letter) {
        times++;
    }
}  

System.out.print("There are "+times+" ocurrances of the letter "+letter
                     +" in the string "+sentence);`
```

Comment: Replace `if (sentence.charAt(posotion) = letter) {` with `if (sentence.charAt(posotion) == letter) {`, for starters. You put an assignation, not comparaison.

Comment: `sentence.charAt(posotion)` -> `sentence.charAt(position)`

Comment: Well that would help if I could spell...

Comment: Have you tried to compile what you have?

Comment: Either there is a typo in your error message or in the code. You should copy+past both.

Comment: Yes I've compiled what I have. I've also fixed the typo and added the proper comparision instead of assignment operator. I now get an error of "incomparable types: char and java.lang.String".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have a typo in your if statement:

```
sentence.charAt(posotion)
```

should be

```
sentence.charAt(position)
```

Then, you are assigning rather than testing equality:

```
if (sentence.charAt(position) = letter) {
```

should be

```
if (sentence.charAt(position) == letter) {
```

Next, you are comparing a char with a string in that if statement. There are several ways to solve this, one way is (assuming `letter` has at least one character):

```
if (sentence.charAt(position) == letter.charAt(0)) {
```

And lastly, you probably don't what to check past the end of the string so:

```
for (position=0; position<=sentence.length(); position++) {
```

should be

```
for (position=0; position<sentence.length(); position++) {
```

Comment: I've fixed the dumb mistakes (long day apparently) and now have the for statement as follows: <br/>            for (position=0; position<sentence.length(); position++) {
            if (sentence.charAt(position) == letter) {
                times++;
            } <br/>The code still does not compile and reads "incomparable types: char and java.lang.String". Is there another variable type that I should be using?

Comment: That's because `charAt()` returns a `char` and `letter` is a `string`. Answer edited.

Comment: So I should technically be ably to just put sentence.charAt(position) == letter.charAt(0) ?   And wow, I look handicapped trying to figure out this website's formatting...

Comment: I got it to work, thank you everyone for your help. And sorry to everyone for seeming illiterate when it came to this, I only started to learn programming last month.